# How to split a string without spaces of continuous delimiter

Tags: java, string, split

how to split the string like `"x~y~z~~~~~"` with delimiter `~`       ,we have to split this as 7 elements. but while processing with `string.split("~")` method it gives 3 strings only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below :

> String[] = data.split("~", -1);

refer  Javadoc for the split method taking two arguments for details.

When calling String.split(String), it calls String.split(String, 0) and that discards trailing empty strings (as the docs say it), when calling String.split(String, n) with n < 0 it won't discard anything.